# combine .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, httpd.conf

I am using the .htaccess mod_rewite directive and want to accomplish 2 different things:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?unit=/$1 [PT,L]
```

The above takes the specified URL and lets me direct it through my index.php bootstrap page.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The above enables my files to be displayed without the .php extension.

Using this I can specify a file using the url `/module/function/setting` and it include the path on the bootstrap page to load up `[root]/module/function/setting.php`.

I need to combine the two actions into 1 statement, can someone help?

Comment: This seems unneeded. Requesting `example.com/page.php` isn't correct. Why not simply ignore ".php" altogether and then append it once the script loads? `$file = getenv('REQUEST_URI') . '.php';` ? (**note** make sure you don't just include things based on the raw URL!)

Comment: Okay I see, yes thats an option. Out of interest, why did you choose to set the REQUEST_URL as an environment variable? Surely Env's are best for static aspects like development/production status? How can I scrub the raw URL, could I use PHP filters?

Comment: the `getenv()` function allows you to access `$_SERVER` variables safely since the web server sets them automatically. `$url =  isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : NULL;` vs `$url = getenv('REQUEST_URI');`

Comment: But are `$_ENV` variables more appropriate than using `$_GET` or simply getting the URL on the index.php? I thought `$_ENV` was conceptually reserved for static variables designed for the system settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the second rule before the first one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?unit=/$1 [PT,L]
```

So htaccess will check if the a script with the name (without the extension) exists and execute it. If not the your currient rule will be executed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a big difference, the url doesn't get .php added.

Comment: Typing example.com/foo should not visibly change but should direct to example.com/index.php/foo.php and example.com/foo/bar should go to example.com/index.php/foo/bar.php - and I can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the /foo/bar.php on index.php (bootstrap file) and bring that content - so I can set variables and also have a consistent method for loading pages

Comment: When navigating to example.com/foo/bar and using `print($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` I'm still getting /foo/bar and not /foo/bar.php but maybe an easier way around this is simply to append the .php to the end of the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` when I receive it?

Comment: Try my least update. But yes it is possible to append the suffix: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].=".php";`